# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have encountered an unfortunate bug when attempting to run my bot written in Node.js.

Whenever attempting to run the init script which calls various other functions of the bot, I am given the following error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined" at various different points in my code. I understand that this is one of the standard functions from JavaScript, so I am unsure why it is giving me an error.

[image: Command Line Errors]

The odd part is these errors are new, and I have run the scripts before many times without running into this issue.

Below is the first error line in [async.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) which shows at line 175.

```
174 function isAsync(fn) {
175    return supportsSymbol && fn[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction';
176 }
```

And a second example is in my own bot_startup.js at line 43.

```
43 connectToServerCallback(null, "connected");
```

It seems like it is erroring out whenever trying to convert data to strings, but I do not know how I would go about fixing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Avoid using the async module; promises exist now! \o/ Anyway, can we see the source of bot_startup.js, please?

Comment: and ../channels/channel_connect.js ?

Comment: Isn't the error message saying that `fn` is undefined?

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise I don't think it wouldn't be giving me an error like that at line 43 in bot_startup

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering, I was able to fix this problem on my own.

The error itself arose from one of the functions being called in async.waterfall not being correctly defined (an error in committing to Git rolled back one of the files it was calling functions from, making the function call no longer valid).

Comment: I have faced the same issue and I couldn't solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773275/using-async-with-mongodb-to-fill-collection-documents-in-order

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was a missing comma in the `async.waterfall()` method call. I received the following error stack:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined
    at isAsync (~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:228:32)
    at wrapAsync (~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:232:12)
    at nextTask (~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5322:20)
    at Object.waterfall (~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5334:5)
    at myFunction (~/path/to/file.js:2318:13)                 // Error was not here
    at nextTask (~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5324:14)
    at next (~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5331:9)
    at ~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
    at myFunction (~/path/to/file.js:2237:16)                 // Error was here
    at nextTask (~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5324:14)
    at next (~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5331:9)
    at ~/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
    at ~/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4669:16
    at ~/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:258:16
    at ~/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4065:11
    at ~/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

Error line:

```
async.waterfall([foo. bar ], cb)
```

Fixed line:

```
async.waterfall([foo, bar ], cb) // NOTE the comma
```

I'm not sure, but if your problem is similar to mine, it could be at line 49 in bot startup.js, as shown in the screenshot.