# Using Async with MongoDb to fill collection documents in order

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async.js

I decided to use Async module to populate a mongodb collection in the order that I want.
Without Async the code works but the documents aren't inserted in the proper order:

```
function insertRowInBLD(ref, riskstatements, maximpact, controleffectiveness, recommendedriskrating, frequency, impact, validatedreviewriskrating, rationalforriskadjustment) {
    const businessLineDashboard = new BusinessLineDashboard({
        ref: ref,
        riskstatements: riskstatements,
        maximpact: maximpact,
        controleffectiveness: controleffectiveness,
        recommendedriskrating: recommendedriskrating,
        frequency: frequency,
        impact: impact,
        validatedreviewriskrating: validatedreviewriskrating,
        rationalforriskadjustment: rationalforriskadjustment
    });
    businessLineDashboard.save()
        .then(row => {
            console.log('row ' + businessLineDashboard.ref + ' has been inserted succesfully');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('err: ', err);
        });
}
```

I wanted the the "documents" to be inserted in that order. Because of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, that didn't happen.  So I tried to use

async.series:

```
function fillBLD() {
    async.series(
        [
            insertRowInBLD('R01', 'Disclosure of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', ''),
            insertRowInBLD('R02', 'Corruption of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', ''),
            insertRowInBLD('R03', 'Unavailability of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', '', '', '', '', ''),
            insertRowInBLD('R04', 'Disclosure of data due to attack of the communications link by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', ''),
            insertRowInBLD('R05', 'Corruption of data due to attack of the communications link by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', ''),
        ]
    );
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> ProjectPath\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of
>   undefined

Any idea what may be causing this error and how can I fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

your `insertRowInBLD` function has to return a `Promise` instance instead of `undefined` as now. `Async.series` is being passed an array of `undefined`.

This.

```js
function fillBLD() {
    async.series(
        [
            insertRowInBLD('R01', 'Disclosure of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', ''),
            insertRowInBLD('R02', 'Corruption of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', ''),
            insertRowInBLD('R03', 'Unavailability of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', '', '', '', '', ''),
            insertRowInBLD('R04', 'Disclosure of data due to attack of the communications link by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', ''),
            insertRowInBLD('R05', 'Corruption of data due to attack of the communications link by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', ''),
        ]
    );
}
```

is actually this.

```js
function fillBLD() {
    async.series(
        [
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :) I will try to fix it using your tip

Comment: I have tried writing this instead of just calling the insertRowInBLD but still it didn't work :    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 36");
      insertRowInBLD('R36', 'Lack of accountability due to tampering with audit trails by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 36 Inserted');
    },

Comment: Although the console logs come out in order. The documents insertion in the collection are still not inserted in order

Comment: if you need to guarantee order you are better of using bulkWrite on the driver with ordered = true. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite

Comment: @chritkv thanks for the tip! Definitely helpful. I will try it out